# D3.js - puzzling interpretation of a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

The JSON file which I am using is being interpreted differently than I would expect.

The external JSON file:

```
{"organizations":[{"member":{"source":"TCAN","target":"Resilient Toronto","category-source":"organization","category-target":"organization"}},{"member":{"source":"City of Toronto","target":"","category-source":"organization","category-target":""}},{"member":{"source":"Resilient Toronto","target":"City of Toronto","category-source":"organization","category-target":"organization"}},{"member":{"source":"Rita Bijons","target":"ZCO","category-source":"volunteer","category-target":"organization"}},{"member":{"source":"Rita Bijons","target":"Green 13","category-source":"volunteer","category-target":"community group"}},{"member":{"source":"Green 13","target":"TCAN","category-source":"community group","category-target":"organization"}},{"member":{"source":"ZCO","target":"TCAN","category-source":"organization","category-target":"organization"}}]}
```

I don't understand why the source field is being interpreted as an object while category-source is not. Is it just because of the name? and why is there a category field in the source object? And the name is undefined? Obviously I am missing some basic understanding. Is there somewhere this is documented?

[image: Console Log output]

Comment: You must be doing some processing on the JSON -- it displays as expected for me http://jsfiddle.net/sndj6/

Comment: Yes... I had to rebuild it completely after our chat. I had to regenerate it for many-to-many relations, and, as you had pointed out the names were mixed up. I just resolved this problem by not using "source" and "target" in the JSON file. Perhaps there was some other (better) solution.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to process the JSON?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/j47t3/ - it is more or less the same as your fiddle we were working on earlier (http://jsfiddle.net/WKL3v/) although I have modified the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running your data through the [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) and it is conflicting with your property name "source".  Specifically, the [force.links](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-links) call will change the data by adding "source" and "target" properties that look just like the structure you reference.

Check to see if you're passing your data into force.links at any point.

Comment: Yes, I am using force.links. I am calling it after using console.log.But clearly I have a lot to learn since I tend to think sequence of functions are significant.

Comment: console.log executes asynchronously so by the time it gets output to the console it has already been changed by a subsequent.  Chrome has actually resolved this problem by making a deep copy of the logged object but I believe Safari (and maybe other WebKit-based browsers) still has the issue.  See this for more: http://techblog.appnexus.com/2011/webkit-chrome-safari-console-log-bug/

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested your JSON with [PrettyPrint](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prettyprint/nipdlgebaanapcphbcidpmmmkcecpkhg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) and it's formatted properly. So it appears that the problem is with the software/code you are using to display(format) the JSON data.

[image]

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question is about why it is interpreted differently from source? They are both strings. I should add that it may be something to do with script that is used following it to access the child objects:         var links=members.organizations.map(function(members) {
        return members.member;
      });

Comment: The console log output was generated immediately after reading in the JSON file. When I changed the attribute names to xsource and xtarget things started to work as expected.